# vsnwprintf alternative on linux

Tags: c, gcc, unicode

What is the direct alternative for the `vsnwprintf` function on linux machines and what headers should be included to use it?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what `vsnwprintf()` *(sic)* does and what is its parameter list.

The [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) describes [`vswprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/vswprintf.html) (in section 7.24.2.7). To use it you need to #include `<stdarg.h>` and `<wchar.h>`. The implementation should be in the Standard library.

Comment: It appears this function is the correct alternative, even without `n` in its name, thanks!

Comment: One of the parameters to `vswprintf()` is the (maximum) size of the output array. It's *only* the return value that is different than the return value of, for example, `snprintf()`.

Comment: Downvoting for the 'sic'. printf -> wprintf, vprintf -> vwprintf, sprintf -> swprintf, vsprintf -> vswprintf.. But vsnwprintf elicits sarcasm from you? It's pretty obvious what it is: v = vararg, s = string-dest, n = numeric limit, w = widestring.

Answer (score 3):

Linux variant of this function is `snprintf` and `vsnprintf` which are kindly provided by `stdio.h`:

```
int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);
int vsnprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, va_list args);
```

and Unicode versions provided by `wchar.h`:

```
int swprintf(wchar_t *wcs, size_t maxlen, const wchar_t *format, ...);
int vswprintf(wchar_t *wcs, size_t maxlen, const wchar_t *format, va_list args);
```

http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf
http://linux.die.net/man/3/swprintf

Comment: I am sorry, you probably missed the `w` in function name, this should be unicode variant with wchar_t paramater

Comment: your reply was not about unicode variant. I will upvote your Q due to edit, np

Answer (score 1):

There’s no alternative for that.

vswprintf suggested in other answers doesn’t tell required buffer length. When you’ll pass nullptr and 0 to the first two arguments, it will returns -1, not the required buffer length. This is both how it's [documented](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/vswprintf/), and how it works in practice in clang 4.

There’s a workaround in that answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16352146/126995
Scroll to the end of that for vscwprintf source code. The workaround works for small strings, but relatively slow for larger strings, and can even exhaust stack space for a very large string.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that [u_vsnprintf()](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustdio_8h.html#aae7e44a6233404268c4ed2eebd661140) or [u_vsnprintf_u()](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustdio_8h.html#a2326d587dca4871d238a0d64e05ea7a4) from libicu is what you need

Answer (score 0):

The truncating version of `vswprintf()` is unsafe. 
You really want the C11 `vswprintf_s()`, which ensures a null delimited wide string, and errors when the destination buffer is too small.

As you know, the wide variants have no API to calculate the size with a NULL buffer. You need to extend the buffer on errors, if the buffer is too small.

Anyway, **safeclib-3.0** will provide all of them.
safe and unsafe with --enable-unsafe, wide or non-wide, truncating ('n') or not-truncating.
https://github.com/rurban/safeclib/blob/wchar/src/wchar/vsnwprintf_s.c

`vsnwprintf` is in C99, MSVC, and a few others. Not in musl.
`-stc=c99` should be enough for glibc.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of workaround:

```
  int vsnwprintf(wchar_t* buffer, size_t size, const wchar_t* format, va_list& params)
  {
    if(buffer || size)
      return vswprintf(buffer, size, format, params);

    int result = -1;
    for(size = 100; result < 0; size += 100)
    {
      unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> guard(buffer = new wchar_t[size]);
      va_list copy;
      va_copy(copy, params);
      result = vswprintf(buffer, size, format, copy);
      va_end(copy);
    }
  
    return result;
  };
```

Probably, it's needed to limit a number of iterations in some way.

Answer (score 0):

For C++, you can use `fmt::sprintf` of [libfmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt#readme) from `<fmt/printf.h>`